# Connecting to couchdb inside docker

Tags: docker, couchdb

I'm trying to setup a Docker image running couchDB that loads some data during the build phase. All that seems to work, but I can't connect it once it's running...

```
curl localhost:5984
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

COPY . .

# Load deps
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils apt-transport-https curl

# Install couchDB
RUN echo "deb https://apache.bintray.com/couchdb-deb xenial main" \
    | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN curl -L https://couchdb.apache.org/repo/bintray-pubkey.asc \
    | apt-key add -

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y couchdb

# Load data
RUN ./myLoadScript.sh

# Expose couchDB port
EXPOSE 5984

# Start couchDB
CMD ["/opt/couchdb/bin/couchdb"]
```

and I build and run it with:

```
docker build --tag=database .
docker run -p 5984:5984 database
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 2):

- CouchDB is accessible by default on localhost which will be localhost
  inside the container since you are using docker.
- you can try **exec** inside the CouchDB container and run **curl
  localhost:5984** and it should work.
- If you want to allow certain IPs to connect to your CouchDB server then you should use bind_address [config_docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/config/http.html).
- To allow all IPs use **bind_address = 0.0.0.0** in **local.ini**.